# Deleting Line of Text Using Xcode Find and Replace

Tags: xcode

I'm wondering if it's possible to search for a certain line of a text using Xcode's Find & Replace feature, and fully delete the line so not even blank space is left over. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: You can replace only the search text matching with what you have searched. You can replace it with empty string using that feature.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Copy the line you want to delete, including the newline character at the end of the line by triple-clicking on it (the selection should go all the way to the far right side of the editor pane). Perform a find and replace; paste the line into the the top field, and leave the replace field blank. Click Replace All.

Comment: At least in Xcode 6.1, requires that you "Find > Text > Containing", rather than e.g. "Find > Text > Matching"

Answer (score 11):

On the latest Xcode you can just insert line break in the search field. Click on magnifying glass icon -> insert pattern -> Line Break

[image]

Comment: It works, but this shifts a line below to the right with two tabs. Any ideas on how to avoid it?

Comment: @BlazejSLEBODA I think you should double-check what text you are replacing to what. Probably the shift comes from your search/replace text, not by the line break itself.